# IDLE returning syntax errors for no reason that I can discern

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

```
# Function starts_with() - Finds if list 1 starts with list 2 : )    
def starts_with(list1, list2):
    count = 0
    if length (list1) >= length(list2):(error)
        for var in range(length(list2):(error)
            if var == list2[var]: (error)
                count(error) += 1
    else:
        return false
    if count = length(list2):
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

This code returns syntax errors at the marked points. Length does the same thing as len, and I realize that I am a horrible programmer.

Comment: What error? What is `length`? Did you define a funciton by that name, or did you mean `len`? This is no SyntaxError, though, but a NameError. Also, what is `true` and `false`? Those should probably be `True` and `False`, but again, no syntax error and you did not even mark those lines.

Comment: I actually stated that length is len effectively, and I can see other errors like you pointed out.. My issue is that I'm getting unexplained syntax errors on the lines marked (error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing those `(error)` markers, there are *two* actual syntax errors in your script:

1. Missing closing parens `)` in `for var in range(length(list2):`
2. Assignment `=` instead of equality check `==` in `if count = length(list2):`

Apart from that, there are some other issues, but those are not syntax errors:

- Should `length` be `len`? Even if you have a function called `length`, that does the same thing as `len`, why not use `len` in the first place?
- Unless you defined "aliases" for those, too, `true` and `false` should be `True` and `False`

For the other places, I can't see what's wrong there, but those might be follow-up errors that are resolved once you fix those other ones. If that does not fix it:

- Check your indentation; make sure to use only tabs or spaces, but not a mixture
- Post the actual Syntax Error you are getting

Comment: Thanks, I realized the error was due to both the assignment instead of equality comparitor and the missing parentheses.